# Dom Config failure server 2008 r2

Tags: asp.net, windows-server-2008

anyone know how to fix the following error?

```
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {0002DF01-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).
```

In the application im trying to get it to open a page and input data at a certain url using SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve it:

Add this `<identity impersonate="true" userName="Domain\MyUsername" password="MyPassword"/>`
in web.config after `<authentication mode="Windows" />`

from

[Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowstransactionsprogramming/thread/782edfee-183d-4f02-935e-cd7735169c6f)

Comment: How did you find out what is domain/username required? :) Is it listed on pressing <WIN>+<PAUSE BREAK> ?

Comment: huh i used the login to the server